# Passing lambda, which returns polymorphic unique_ptr, as function pointer

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers, c++14

I want to pass a non-capturing lambda, which returns a 
`std::unique_ptr<Derived>`, as a function pointer of type `std::unique_ptr<Base>(*)()`.

However, this only works if I explicitly state the return type of the lambda as `std::unique_ptr<Base>`.

- Why do I have explicitly state the return type?
- Why does it work for a `std::function` without this extra return type?

---

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

struct Base{virtual ~Base()=default;};
struct Derived : Base{};

struct FailsForF2
{
   using Function = std::add_pointer_t<std::unique_ptr<Base>()>;
   FailsForF2(Function f) {}
};

struct Works
{
   using Function = std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base>()>;
   Works(Function f) {}
};


std::unique_ptr<Derived> fun() {return std::make_unique<Derived>();} 

int main()
{

   auto f1 = [](){return std::make_unique<Base>();};
   auto f2 = [](){return std::make_unique<Derived>();};
   auto f3 = []()->std::unique_ptr<Base>{return std::make_unique<Derived>();};

   Works x1(f1);
   Works x2(f2);
   Works x3(f3);

   FailsForF2 x4(f1);
   FailsForF2 x5(f2);
   FailsForF2 x6(f3);
}
```

**gcc error**:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:34:20: error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'main()::<lambda()>' to 'FailsForF2::Function {aka std::unique_ptr<Base> (*)()}' [-fpermissive]

    FailsForF2 x5(f2);

                    ^

main.cpp:26:17: note: candidate is: main()::<lambda()>::operator std::_MakeUniq<Derived>::__single_object (*)()() const <near match>

    auto f2 = [](){return std::make_unique<Derived>();};

                 ^

main.cpp:26:17: note:   no known conversion from 'std::_MakeUniq<Derived>::__single_object (*)() {aka std::unique_ptr<Derived> (*)()}' to 'FailsForF2::Function {aka std::unique_ptr<Base> (*)()}'

main.cpp:10:4: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'FailsForF2::FailsForF2(FailsForF2::Function)'

    FailsForF2(Function f) {}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/557ce19ce859a6d4)

Comment: wouldn't `std::add_pointer_t<std::unique_ptr<Base>>;` be a pointer to a `unique_ptr<base>`? See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a1c461bfb6199a8 

I may be no expert here but I can guess the compiler has a problem converting a `unique_ptr<derrived>` to a pointer to a `unique_ptr<base>` while converting a `unique_ptr<base>` to a pointer to `unique_ptr<base>` it can somehow do implicitly

Comment: @Hayt I use `std::add_pointer_t<std::unique_ptr<Base>()>;` please note the `( )` at the end

Comment: Ah yeah right. Nevermind that then.It maybe has to do something with the different behavior of a function ptr (which the first is) and a function object with some conversion but I could not find any links to that right now (in combinations to lambdas. There may be somethings with converison of a lambda to a c-function ptr also).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

- `FailsForF2` fails because `std::unique_ptr<Derived> (*) ()` is not implicitly convertible to `std::unique_ptr<Base> (*) ()`;
- `Works` works because `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` is implicitly convertible to `std::unique_ptr<Base>` (see the standard quotes at the end).

---

A lambda is implicitly convertible to a function pointer with the same return type and arguments<sup>1</sup>, so your three lambdas are respectively convertible to:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> (*) ()
std::unique_ptr<Derived> (*) ()
std::unique_ptr<Base> (*) ()
```

Since `std::unique_ptr<Derived> (*) ()` is different from (and not convertible to) `std::unique_ptr<Base> (*) ()`, there is no viable overload for `FailsForF2` constructor. See with the following piece of code:

```
std::unique_ptr<Derived> (*pfd) () = f2; // Compiles.
std::unique_ptr<Base> (*pfb) () = pfd;   // Does not compile (invalid conversion).
```

When you explicitly specify the return type of the lambda, you change the return type of the call operator of the lambda (the closure type associated to it actually, see the quote at the end), so the conversion is possible.

---

`std::function` on the other hand does not have such constraints - The constructor of `std::function` is templated so it can take any callable:

```
template <typename F>
std::function(F &&f);
```

...as long as the following is valid<sup>2</sup>:

```
INVOKE(f, std::forward<Args>(args)..., R)
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Standard quote from N4594, §5.1.5/7 (emphasis is mine):</sub>

> <sub>The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a conversion function to pointer to function with C++ language linkage (7.5) having **the same parameter and return types** as the
>   closure type’s function call operator. [...]</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Standard quote from N4594, §20.12.12.2/2:</sub>

> <sub>A callable object f of type F is Callable for argument types ArgTypes and return type R if the expression `INVOKE (f, declval<ArgTypes>()..., R)`, considered as an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), is well formed (20.12.2).</sub>

<sub>...and §20.12.2 (emphasis is mine, 1.1 through 1.6 are about pointer (or alike) to member functions, so not relevant here):</sub>

> <sub><sup>1</sup> Define `INVOKE (f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` as follows:</sub>
>
> <sub>(1.x) - [...]</sub>
>
> <sub><sup>(1.7)</sup> - `f(t1, t2, ..., tN)` in all other cases.</sub>
>
> <sub><sup>2</sup> Define `INVOKE (f, t1, t2, ..., tN, R)` as static_cast(`INVOKE (f, t1, t2, ..., tN)`) if R is cv void, otherwise `INVOKE (f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` **implicitly converted to R**.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Holt's answer, and to cover your first question: You don't necessarily have to specify the return type explicitly as a trailing return type. But since you're creating a `unique_ptr<Derived>`, but want a `unique_ptr<Base>`, you should return the latter and perform the conversion within your function.

So, I believe, that's something along the lines of

```
auto f2 = [](){ return std::unique_ptr<Base>{new Derived()}; };
```

which also compiles.

Comment: @m.s. There is no exception safety issue here (but I agree that in general you should go for `make_unique`), but if you need you could `std::unique_ptr<Base>(std::make_unique<Derived>())` (which is basically what `f3` does implicitly, or the `std::function` version) - But if you need the conversion to function pointer, the best way is to explicitly specify the return type as in `f3`.